# Remapping only left command key in Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, keyboard, command, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to remap only the left command key in my .emacs file instead of changing both at once? I want to remap <kbd>Left Cmd ⌘</kbd> to become <kbd>Meta</kbd>. I used:

```
(setq ns-command-modifier 'meta)
```

but I only want <kbd>Left Cmd ⌘</kbd> to be remapped while keeping <kbd>Right Cmd ⌘</kbd> as is in order to close Emacs when needed, open new tabs or frames, etc. Alternatively, I could just remap another key to become the new <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> but how would I do that?

Comment: Check out the variable `ns-right-command-modifier`.  Perhaps if you set that combined with setting `ns-command-modifier` differently, you might be able to achieve the result you seek.  Also, check out `M-x customize-group RET ns RET`  However, I've never tried setting those variables so you'll need to experiment.  FYI:  When you use broad topic tags, you'll likely reach an audience that knows nothing about Emacs and could probably care less -- those people are the most likely to down-vote and/or vote to close, and they'll likely give you answers that are not necessarily on point.